# The number of characters of hexadecimal numbers

Tags: numbers, hexadecimal

`0xF`, `0x0000000F` (total width is 10 characters), and `0x0000000000000000F` (total width is 18 characters) all mean `15` (decimal).

Is it correct to say that there is no reason to add leading zeros to a smaller hex number beyond 10 characters in total? In other words, is it correct to say that anything longer than the second version is excessive?

Comment: @DocBrown I'm total newbie in the area of hex numbers and so I'm not really aware about how they work. I just can't answer it. (And it's completely OK for this question to be downvoted.)

Comment: @jsv _"I'm not really aware about how they work"_ Well, just like decimal numbers do, only with base 16 instead of 10. They are often used to represent binary numbers (base 2) because they are easier to read and fit well with the format.

Comment: Hexadecimal is just a different way to write numbers. There is nothing different about the numbers themselves.

Comment: Should we write 15, 00000015, or 0000000000000015?

Comment: It doesn't directly answer the question, but it helps to better understand _the_ answers: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

Comment: @DocBrown you pinged the wrong person

Comment: @DocBrown Yes, it looks more accurate, thanks.

Comment: @user253751: If these are decimal numbers, you shouldn't add leading zeroes, so 15 is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hexadecimal numbers are typically used to represent binary data which have a fixed size in bytes. Hex numbers are prefixed with zeroes so the number of digits match the range.

So if you write a byte value as hex, you always write 2 hex digits, even if the number is below 16. You write `0A`, not `A` or `00A` even though they are technically the same number.

This is especially important when writing sequences of hex numbers. For example the two byte sequence `0A 0D` could in theory be written as `A D` but then it would not be clear anymore that it is a two byte sequence. And if you write `000A 000D` it would be interpreted as a 4-byte sequence which is quite different!

You use 4 hex digits to write a 16-bit value, 8 digits for a 32 bit value, 16 digits for a 64 bit value and so forth.

So there are contexts where you would use a large number of zeroes. Lets say you write the contents of a 64-bit register - writing `0x000000000000000F` is entirely appropriate. It would be confusing if you left out some of the zeroes. (Although you would probably use spaces or separators to make it more readable like  `0x0000 0000 0000 000F`).

In contrast you would typically never add leading zeroes to a decimal number, since the leading zeroes does not carry any information. (Indeed, in some programming languages, a leading zero would cause a decimal number to be interpreted as an octal number.)

Comment: _"You use 4 hex digits to write a 16-bit value, 8 digits for a 32 bit value, 16 digits for a 64 bit value and so forth."_ - And `0x0A` is a 8-bit value, and so it requires only 2 hex digits and not 4?

Comment: @jsv: Yes, an 8bit value (one byte) only require 2 hex digits.

Comment: My comments got deleted, but I'll reiterate: this was a blatant rip off of my answer. It's improved a bit with the edit 3 hours, but that's still not cool.

Comment: Sort of relevant is the scheme used to abbreviate 128 bit IPv6 addresses whereby for example   2001:0db8:3c4d:0015:0000:0000:1a2f:1a2b becomes 2001:db8:3c4d:15::1a2f:1a2b

Comment: @PeterM. How is IPv6 address shortening relevant?

Comment: A prefix of zero, not followed by 'x' or 'X', is regarded as an octal number (AKA octal constant)  in the C and C++ languages

Comment: @fpmurphy IPv6 abbreviation removes the redundant zeroes when representing a 128 bit number.  This is an extension of removing just leading zeroes from a number as per what the OP's question was about.

Answer (score 6):

The "appropriate" format is typically context dependent.

For example, if you're working in the context of a CPU with 64 bit registers, it might be more appropriate to write `0x0000 0000 0000 0003` instead of `0x3`, just so that the register's width is communicated.

But in general, it's not much different than decimal numbers. If you have a `$1,000` in your bank account, you wouldn't write `$0,001,000` to be in the 6-zeros club

Comment: LOL. If you don't use lading zero's, I guess there are very few people (or even organisations) with 6 or more zero's on their bank account balance value.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Especially when $1074952.14 doesn't count! That's only one zero! To have an expected 6 zeroes, they should have about a 60-digit bank balance.

Comment: An assembler is is going to complain if you write a 64-bit immediate value as `0x0000 0000 0000 0003` -  for example `MOV RAX, 0x0000 0000 0000 0003`

Comment: @fpmurphy Yep. The format I suggested was more for user readability (e.g. a stack trace)

Comment: @fpmurphy: NASM allows writing `0x0000_0000_0000_0003` and I think recent revisions of C and C++ allow inserting I believe apostrophes for the same purpose.

Comment: Guys, I think you're missing the point. There are many, many different formats of pointers, let alone decimal numbers. All I'm showing is that there is a benefit to occasionally including leading zeros. Various assemblers and tools are free to use all kinds of different strategies spacing, abbreviation, etc.